# Prove if $n=p_1p_2\cdots p_k +1$, then for every $i$, $i=1,2,\cdots k, p_i$ does not divide n.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I am trying to prove

> Let $p_1, p_2, \cdots p_k$ be prime integers. if $n = p_1p_2\cdots p_k + 1$ then for every $i$, $i =1, 2\cdots,k$, $p_i$ does not divide n.

I start with contradiction;

**Proof:**
Suppose $p_i$ divide n, we would have $p_i|n$ which equal to $p_im=n$ where $m$ is an integer.

then $$p_i m=p_1p_2...p_k+1$$ $$\Rightarrow p_im - p_1p_2...p_k=1$$

since $\{p_1,p_2,...,p_k\} = \bigcup_{i=1}^{k}p_i$, we can factor out one of prime number of $p_im - p_1p_2...p_k=1$, then we have $p_i(m-j)=1$ where $j=p_1p_2\cdots p_{k-i}\cdots p_k$.

let $m-j = l$ where $l$ is an integer, such that $p_i l=1$.

we have $p_i l=1$  equal to $p_i|1$, which is a contradiction;
therefore $p_i$ does not divide n.

I think my proof still missing some details need to show, can someone tell me what I still need to say or give me a hit or suggestion to write a better proof?

Thanks!

Comment: All you need is a lemma: If $p\mid 1$ then $p$ is not prime. Contradiction is not necessary for the rest of the proof.

Comment: Your proof seems more or less OK as it is. It could probably be slightly shorter, rather than longer. Strictly, you should say that $\{p_{1}, \ldots, p_{n} \} = \cup_{i=1}^{n} \{ p_{i} \}.$

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea but have said it in what is, in my opinion, too many words.
I would say if $p_k$ divides $p_1\cdots p_n +1$ then $p_k$ divides $(p_1\cdots p_n+1) - p_1\cdots p_k = 1$ but this implies $p_k=1$ because the only positive way to factor $1$ is $1=1\cdot 1$). Thus we have our contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is fine, all you need is that a prime cannot be a divisor of $1$, since all primes are greater than $1$.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

If there's a $p_i$ which divides $n$, then it would also divide $n - p_1p_2...p_k$, that's $1$. This means that $p_i = 1$, so $1$ is prime. A contradiction.